# Retrieve columns in array from elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch

I have:

```
1    2    3    4    5
1    55   4    8    7
8    6    80   40   1
```

I have my `pandas` `dataframe` saved on `elasticsearch` `index`, each row is a document.
Now I want to retrieve all columns that  are in list `[1,5]`

i.e. output shall be:

```
1    5
1    7
8    1
```

When I do :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
res = es.search(index="index_name", body={ "query": {"match_all": {}}})
df = json_normalize(res['hits']['hits'])
```

I get my `dataframe`, but I don't want to load it completely, just want to retrieve specific columns, how do I do so?

**Probably this won't help me completely, but will be done via filter only** [ES filter-term-array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html)

## UPDATED

Documents on ES are like:

```
{
    "_index": "index_name",
    "_type": "dataframe",
    "_id": "0",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "1": 1,
      "2": 55,
      "3": 4,
      "4": 8,
      "5": 7,
      "index": 0
}
```

## UPDATE 2

Obviously I can do:

```
df[[1,5]] or
df[:,[1,5]]
```

or something else with `pandas`
But for that I have to first load my entire `dataframe`, what if `dataframe` is way too large? I don't want to fill up my whole memory by a single `dataframe` as I have different tasks going on, I just want to load in required columns from elasticsearch, this is more of `elasticsearch` `query` question than `pandas`.

Comment: df[[1,5]]  something like this?

Comment: @anky_91 updated question please see